# Effect of Online Compiler on computer's memory

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

When we declare any variable, particularly in C/C++, it is allocated in computer’s memory according to its data-type (and machine also). The question I have is, when we run the program in online IDEs, does memory of my PC/machine get used?

This question is meant more for the matter of dynamically allocating memory in C, because, for whatever reason, if we misuse the pointer in arguments of function like `malloc()`, `calloc()`, especially `free()`, it is possible that computer memory gets damaged to some extent (Memory Leakage).

Therefore, if online compilation do not use the computer memory, then I can probably use these functions on an online IDE, but I don't know what the case is. Is it safe?

Comment: Even if you run the program locally, there is no "damage" to the computer's memory. A memory leak just means that if you call `malloc` *a lot* more that `free`, the calls will eventually fail. That's all. As soon as the program terminates, the OS will sort things out again and release all the memory that the program was using.

Comment: This is the excerpt from C : The complete referece by Schildt. 

The `free( )` function returns the memory pointed to by ptr to the heap. This makes the memory available for future allocation.
It is imperative that `free( )` only be called with a pointer that was previously allocated using one of the dynamic allocation system's functions. Using an invalid pointer in the call most likely will destroy the memory management mechanism and possibly cause a system crash. If you pass a null pointer, `free( )` performs no operation.

Comment: Yeah, but if you run any modern operating system, like Linux or Windows or OSX, the entire heap is in virtual memory which is reclaimed when the program terminates. Each program has its own heap and cannot cause any damage to each other.

Comment: Okay first things first don't use anything from Schildt he may be the worst reference for C possible. See: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/schildt.html and http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html

Comment: "memory leak" does not mean there are electrons dripping out of your memory, so youhave a pool of free electrons around your PC.

Comment: And when you free a non allocated pointer the worst thing that can happen on a modern OS is a runtime error for your program other process should not care about this.

Comment: @Olaf ,I know that. :D :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since everything runs on the remote machine, your local PC will not be affected by anything happening over there.

Comment: I've also heard from my professor that you should not use online stuffs which is related to memory, it is always mistaken. Is this true ? Though, I've not experienced any compilation mistake regarding pointers, till now.

Comment: Anything that fails, fails on the remote machine. Including memory corruption. The only way to affect your local machine is by "zero day" exploits in your browser.

Answer (score 3):

An online compiler does not access your computer's local memory; all the runnning process takes place on a remote machine. Hence, your computer is unaffected by an online compiler, even if you use functions like `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or even `free()`.

For example, Ideone, a popular online compiler, runs submitted code on a remote server owned by Sphere Engine. The memory allocation, compilation, running, etc... all take place on that server. Other online compilers make use of similar services.

Note that having said the above; if the compiler lags, or if your code is faulty (like if it goes into an unintended infinite loop), then your browser may experience lag or it may hang (as it does sometimes in my case). But that has nothing to do with your computer's memory, as only the open browser is affected and everything else should work fine. The reason this lag takes place is because of some issue on the remote server, which is experiencing lag due to faulty code, or slow processing speed, etc... Also, your internet speed may be slow, which may result in some lag. However, saying it again, this has nothing to do with the local memory of your machine.

This last paragraph was an extra side-note to the main question.

Comment: Thanks for extra side-note.

Answer (score 2):

They are typically web services. They receive the program and compile, link and run it in a sandbox (on the server) and only return the output to the end-user. While I cannot comment on all of them, this is the typical behavior. So in general, they are safe and they do not use your computer memory for running the code.

Comment: I've also heard from my professor that you should not use online stuffs which is related to memory, it is always mistaken. Is this true ? Though, I've not experienced any compilation mistake regarding pointers, till now.

Comment: In my idea, it is actually a good place as a playground for starting to learn coding. Since you don't corrupt your own computer's memory which is typically the case with the new programmers trying to manipulate pointers in a language like C. Maybe what your professor wanted to point out is that you don't have any power on choosing the size of the memory of the sandbox that you are running your code in ( in case you allocate large memory) or other performance related specs.

Comment: @arash You probably have even more layers of abstractions between you and the system memory. While in C its already quite abstract (to the point that we don't have real addresses for pointers, there is a mapper in between that can map this to virtual memory), in an online compiler you might have even more abstraction that can get you confused.

Comment: @Kami Kaze. I see. Good point about more layers of abstractions. :-)

Comment: I think I should have tagged @HardeyPandya because as this is a comment to your (arash) answer you get notified and he maybe doesn't

Comment: Yes, I got notified now at this moment.  :)